# GridView retrieve Data in every Row

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the Rows are bounding I need to take a specif value Ex FirstName and change with some logic the label which show the FirstName field.

I am using this script with no success..

How Can I access the field? Thanks

```
 protected void uxListAuthorsDisplayer_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
        switch (e.Row.RowType)
        {
            // In case type of row is DataRow (a data row of GridView) 
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                e.Row.DataItem[1].Value.ToString();
                break;
        }
 }
```

Comment: @Glbbok pls specify the question correclty.From here I understood that you want to change the label in the gridview for a particular field.Are you using ItemTemplate in gridview.Pls provide some info about the gridview

Comment: thanks for your message, YES i am using a ItemTemplate in gridview. So I would like change the content of this label in some case.. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
e.Row.Cells[x].Text
```

Where x is your column index?